# AngularJS ngResource $resource query() Returns Empty

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-resource

I am trying to upload a file from the server but the file is not showing up. The call to the server is initiated from this segment of code:

```
'use strict';

angular.
module('phoneList').
component('phoneList', {
  templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
  controller: ['Phone',
    function PhoneListController(Phone) {
      this.phones = Phone.query();
      this.orderProp = 'age';
      console.log(this.phones);
    }
  ]
});
```

Which calls this service:

```
'use strict';

angular.
module('core.phone').
factory('Phone', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          phoneId: 'phones'
        },
        isArray: true
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

The return codes are 200 and subsequently 304 which indicate a successful upload.  But the console.log statement in the earlier code segment does not display the phones in the console.

Comment: The formatter did not work as expected

Answer (score 1):

To log the result, use the `$promise` property of the `$resource` object:

```
angular.
module('phoneList').
component('phoneList', {
  templateUrl: 'phone-list/phone-list.template.html',
  controller: ['Phone',
    function PhoneListController(Phone) {
      this.phones = Phone.query();
      this.orderProp = 'age';
      //console.log(this.phones);
      //USE $promise property
      this.phones.$promise.then(function(phones) {
          console.log(phones);
      }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log("ERROR " + error.status);
      });
    }
  ]
});
```

It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on `isArray`). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

By using the `.then` method of the `$promise` property, the $q service delays the `console.log` until the data has returned from the server.